# Uploadify with Codeigniter 3 loosing cookie/session

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, uploadify

I am having some issues with Codeigniter 3 session.
On the previous version, it was working fine until I upgraded to CI3.
I implemented uplodify which is a file/image uploader.

The code is too long to post here, I try to simplify it.
Here is add photo view file:

```
 <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />

   <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {

   browser_cookie = $.cookie('<?=$this->session->sess_cookie_name?>');
   $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'debug'   : false,
  'uploader'  : '<?=site_url("/photo/uploadFile")?>',
  'swf'  : '<?php echo base_url()?>uploadify/uploadify.swf',
  'formData':{'bizid':<?=$biz->id?>,'browser_cookie':browser_cookie},
  'buttonText'  : 'Télécharger',
  'fileTypeExts'     : '*.jpg;',
  'fileTypeDesc'    : 'JPG Files',
  'cancelImg' : '<?php echo base_url()?>uploadify/cancel.png',

  'folder'    : '<?php echo base_url()?>tmp',
  'multi'     : true,
  'queueSizeLimit' : 4,
  'auto'      : true,
```

This code redirects to uploadFile method

```
   'uploader'  : '<?=site_url("/photo/uploadFile")?>',
```

This one fetch the serialized session.

browser_cookie = $.cookie('session->sess_cookie_name?>');

and stores it here.

This part is fine 'bizid':id?>.

'formData':{'bizid':id?>,'browser_cookie':browser_cookie},

Photo controller:

```
 Class Photo extends CI_controller
 {
 // This method checks if user is logged in. It works fine..
public function upload()
{
    if(!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
    {
        redirect('/ucp/login/');
    }
}

    public function uploadFile()
   {
    //This one, is giving me hard time. The session gets lost. 

    if(!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
    {
        $data['type'] = 0;
        $data['msg'] = 'S\'il vous plaît connecter vous pour continuer';
        exit(json_encode($data));
    }
```

If I do

var_dump($this->tank_auth->get_username());

inside upload method, it returns the result. But if I do it inside uploadFile method it returns null.

Here is the query cookie function:

```
     /*jshint eqnull:true */
     /*!
     * jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.1
     * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
     *
     * Copyright 2011, Klaus Hartl
     * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
     * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
     * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/GPL-2.0
     */

  (function($, document) {

var pluses = /\+/g;
function raw(s) {
    return s;
}
function decoded(s) {
    return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
}

$.cookie = function(key, value, options) {

    // key and at least value given, set cookie...
    if (arguments.length > 1 && (!/Object/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(value)) || value == null)) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.cookie.defaults, options);

        if (value == null) {
            options.expires = -1;
        }

        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
            var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
        }

        value = String(value);

        return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
    }

    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
    options = value || $.cookie.defaults || {};
    var decode = options.raw ? raw : decoded;
    var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
    for (var i = 0, parts; (parts = cookies[i] && cookies[i].split('=')); i++) {
        if (decode(parts.shift()) === key) {
            return decode(parts.join('='));
        }
    }
    return null;
};

$.cookie.defaults = {};

})(jQuery, document);
```

How could I get the session to work inside uploadFile method?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploadify doesn't pass the current session information. Codeigniter has changed the way cookies/sessions are handled. So, your jquery cookie fetch won't work.
You try to carry the session like this:

```
 'formData':{'bizid':<?=$biz->id?>,'browser_cookie':<?php echo 'your session here'?>},
```

Then in your controller, you can verify if the session exist. And if not, just set a new session then use it. This should work just fine.